# How to display SQL Server table indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, database-schema

I need to list/display all the clustered and non clustered indexes contained by a table.

How can I do that using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    i.*
FROM 
    sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE
    T.Name = 'YourTableName'
```

If you need more information (like columns contained in the index, their datatype etc.) - you can expand your query to something like this:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    IndexName = i.Name, 
    IndexType = i.type_desc,
    ColumnOrdinal = Ic.key_ordinal,
    ColumnName = c.name,
    ColumnType = ty.name
FROM 
    sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE 
    t.name = 'YourTableName' 
ORDER BY
    t.Name, i.name, ic.key_ordinal
```

These system catalog views contain a wealth of information about your system....

Comment: Or useful shortcut `Alt` + `F1`